# Change View content in activity dynamically

Tags: android, android-view

My abstract class extended from `Activity` class consists of three `View`s as described in the following XML snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/bg">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/top_border">
        ...
    </LinearLayout>

    <View 
        android:id="@+id/activity_content"
        ...
        />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/bottom_border">
        ...          
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And in `onCreate()` method I set this XML-layout as content view.

I want the `Activity`s which extend this one to override `onCreate()` and there define the activity_content `View` remaining borders immutable.

For example like this:

```
abstract public class MyActivity extends Activity {
   protected View mContent;

   @Override
   protected onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.common_layout);
      initializeContent();
   }

   abstract void initializeContent();  
}

class OneActivity extends MyActivity {

   @Override
   protected void initializeContent() {
      mContent = View.inflate(this, R.layout.some_view, null); // i.e. concrete View (e.g. LinearLayout, FrameLayout, GridView, etc.)
   }
}
```

But when I do so my mContent remain the same as it was when I defined it in `MyActivity`'s `onCreate()`.

How can I change view's type/content depends on what `Activity` is in foreground?

Comment: Hi, If I understood you well what you want is to have a template with some fixed layout and some dinamyc. If is like this I encourage you to use Fragments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First change the view in your main layout into a view group (for example, a `LinearLayout`). Then you can **add views to it**. If you add a unique view, it will have exactly the effect you want to achieve.

```
class OneActivity extends MyActivity {
   @Override
   protected void initializeContent() {
      final ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.activity_content);
      viewGroup.addView(View.inflate(this, R.layout.some_view, null)); 
   }
}
```

In your case that should work. If your custom view group contained other views from higher up in the hierarchy, you can clean it before adding your custom view:

```
viewGroup.removeAllViews();
```

It works, I do exactly that in most of my projects.

An alternative is to look at the [Fragments API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html), available for latest versions of the SDK.

Comment: Another benefit of using a ViewGroup is that you can modify its layout (background, width/height, etc.) only in one place, and all your subclass activities will be impacted

Answer (score 0):

You can't override class data members in Java, use methods instead